# Divide with remainder using logical 'and' instruction [Assembly Language 80x86]

Tags: assembly

So I have these *very* basic questions for my assembly class's homework and I have been able to solve all of them except this one...

The questions are simply asking us to supply a logical instruction that will solve the question asked.

This particular one is:

> Give an "and" instruction that stores the remainder of the number in
>   EAX when divide by 16.

I am well aware what the 'and' instruction does (as well as the other logical instructions available in 80x86 architecture) but I am not sure how I am supposed to divide a number with remainder using only one AND instruction.

Normally I would do `shr eax, 4` to divide EAX by 16 but our teacher didn't teach us how to divide with remainder by using logical instructions. I am sure the answer is blatantly obvious to you assembly pros out there.

Comment: `shr eax, 4` chops off the 4 lowest bits which are of course the remainder. You can use `and` to keep those 4 bits and chop off the top 24.

Comment: so it would just be `and eax, 0000000Fh` ?

Comment: It's also blatantly [obvious to every C compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/HwwbmQ).  Reading (and understanding) compiler output is a great way to learn asm tricks.

Comment: @AlexHail yeah that's all. (I meant top 28, in case anybody noticed ;))

Comment: Remainder of division by 16 is some number from [0,15] range. That should be already a hint. Then if you would display binary form of few numbers (1 to 20), and display binary form of remainder after div 16 (using "excel" sheet is simple way to do that within 5 minutes), it would become blatantly obvious.

Comment: But that hint of `shr x,4` was already huge hint. If quotient is extracted by discarding 4 bits, then the remainder depends on them completely, as quotient + remainder (+divisor) can be used to re-create original value. So no bit of information can be lost. You can think about the diversity of information in the amount of bits which are used to encode the information (especially handsome way of thinking in security IT, where number of bits of entropy is base part of cipher strength). When it's clear remainder depends fully on 4 bits, you search for needed conversion to get remainder -> none.